# Call onclick="function(this);" on load?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox with the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="function(this);" checked="checked" />
```

But in same cases I want the call to be made on page load.
How do I replicate the "this" manually?

I tried adding onload="function(this);" to the input, but that didn't work.
And if I just call "function();" on page load then the function naturally doesn't work.

So it'd be great if I could manually call a function like: function(htmlElement[check]); or whatever "this" constitutes.

Hope I've made myself clear :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `this` will refer to the `input` element. Since that element has an ID, you can easily get a reference to it with the `getElementById` method):

```
yourFunction(document.getElementById("check"));
```

You can place that in the `onload` attribute of the `body` element, but ideally, stop using inline event handlers and use the `addEventListener` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
onload="function(document.getElementById('check'));"
```

Comment: this is a little bit unnecessary isnt it? to check whether a part of the html is loaded?

Comment: I think you need to check if the dom has been loaded before calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the element via id, and do it in the `window.onload` callback function.

```
window.onload = function () {
  yourFunction(document.getElementById('check'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to the extent of my understanding, onload only works on `<body>` tag

What you might want to try, is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

source:http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: There is no mention of jQuery anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        document.removeEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, false );
        yourFunction(document.getElementById("check"));     
}, false );
```

You must avoid using:

```
window.onload = function() {
}
```

because in this way you will overide attached to onload functions (if there is already attached to onload with this way). This method is very good when you want to have JavaScript in separate file (the best solution).